Why "onto" instead of just "to" in this isomorphism definition?
From the Axler's book "Linear Algebra Done Right":

Assuming that V and W are finite-dimensional vector spaces.Prove that the map that takes $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ to $T'\in\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ onto $\mathcal{L}(W',V')$.

If the map in question is an isomorphism,then it is a bijective function so "onto"(instead of "to") just serves to emphasize the surjectivity ? Or it just antecipate the "obvious" fact that such map is surjective, if so why the question is not "prove that the (surjective) map that (...) is injective" instead (to avoid redundancy)?

Sometimes a bit of extra additional emphasis added on top is helpful.

I don't know if this is how Axler uses the term that way, but in some contexts I have seen people using the word isomorphism to just mean isomorphism onto its image (i.e. not necessarily onto)
